# Proper usage of plural/singular verb

Tags: grammar, verbs

I wanted to ask, which of these two is correct. I would be grateful for your answer.

> People’s lives is involved.
>   Or
>
> People’s lives are involved.

2nd is grammatically correct, I  think.

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject is the plural noun *lives*; ergo, the verb must be plural, *are*, not singular. Your answer is correct.